# firebase.database.ref("...").set({}) creates a new object instead of updating the existing one.

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm building a like/dislike system for posts on my website. Every time the user clicks on the like button, the number of likes gets updated in the database. The object stored in the database has a url of the image, a category and the number of likes as its keys.

Following is my update code: likedButton(img) is a function which is called when the user clicks the like button.

```
likedButton(img) {
    var url = img.src;
    var x = this.db.list('/userPosts',

  ref => ref.orderByChild('url').equalTo(url));


  x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(

    (datas) => { 
      var keys  = datas[0]['key'];
      var obj = x.valueChanges().subscribe((z) => {
        var n = z[0]['likes'];
        n++;
        console.log(n);
        firebase.database().ref('/userPosts'+keys+'/likes').set({
          'likes' : n
      });


      });

    });
  }
}
```

I want the existing value of "likes" to be updated. But the function ends of creating a new object.

Comment: You say "as its keys", is the number of likes in the key?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen my object in database is: {key: " ", likes: " " , url: " " , catergory: " "}

Comment: Are you sure the url you want to update isn't `/userPosts/key`? Why is `likes` part of the reference?

Answer (score 0):

You should use update instead as calling set on object will replace it completely or create new record if non existed

firebase.database().ref('/userPosts'+keys+'/likes').update({ 'likes' : n})

Comment: your '/userPosts'+keys+'/likes' is missing /... try firebase.database().ref('/userPosts/'+keys+'/likes').update({ 'likes' : n})